# Custom Reusable UI Components in Windows 8 Metro UI HTML Apps

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In the course of creating an app for Metro via HTML/JS/CSS, I've noticed (as is often the case with web-type apps) that there are common UI components which are shared across the site. In the interest of getting it done quickly, I've been copying and pasting, for example, the navigation AppBar from page to page (it's required in some but not all pages, otherwise I'd put it in the navigation parent).

This approach is starting to bug me for a couple of reasons:

- If I add elements to my navigation, which happens reasonably often at this stage in the development, I have to copy and paste HTML+ JS for the nav elements into each page which has navigation.
- My individual page's HTML and JS files are getting polluted with code which is not relevant to the purpose of the page.
- Any developer could come up with a host of other reasons why this is not a great approach.

I'd like to be able to define my own custom control which encapsulates the navigation functionality into its own set of HTML/JS/CSS (similar to how the navigator loads child pages into the default html page). It would also be nice to pass options into such a control (I suppose via "data-win-options" attributes). This is more-or-less equivalent to ASP.Net User Controls or ASP.Net MVC Partials (and any other web client framework, I'm sure).

Unfortunately, at this stage, there isn't really a lot of documentation around to guide me as to how I should go about doing such a thing - or if there is I haven't seen it yet (I've found resources related to the C# and XAML approaches, just not HTML).

So with that in mind, my questions are:

- Is this a good way to approach the problem? (I believe it is but would be interested to hear other opinions if there are any).
- Are there any existing samples online which demonstrate a reasonably elegant solution to the problem - and if so, where are the samples located? Of course, you're welcome to post solutions in answers here if you have them - and I'm sure Stack Overflow would love it if you did...

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample that demonstrates creating a custom control here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SemanticZoom-for-custom-4749edab

The sample is designed to illustrate implementing Semantic Zoom in a custom control, but it should at least help from the standpoint of showing you a sample custom control.

As far as the app bar is concerned, is there a reason you can't have the app bar hosted in your default.html, and add/remove buttons as needed in the child pages when you load them? For pages not requiring the app bar, you could disable it.

Hope that helps.